# What is the best sensor to use in a wearable device to monitor body temperature on a continuous basis: Thermistor, RTD or a semiconductor device?

Tags: sensor, temperature, thermistor, rtd, wearable

Most wrist-worn wearables on the market today don’t seem to feature body temperature sensing which makes me wonder if all these sensors are inadequate in some ways.

Comment: Uh, no, it's because body temperature isn't very important to monitor.

Comment: I think you mean thermistor, not thyristor.  In any case, it is difficult to get a good indication of body temperature from a wrist-worn device.

Comment: have you ever tried measuring the temperature of your body purely through the surface of it, exposed to the air?

Comment: yes, I did mean thermistor, sorry

Comment: Well edit your post then!

Comment: IR sensor in the ear.

Comment: @Barry But what a selling point! Heart rate monitor, now with thyristor based body temperature sensor. I would buy it! Wouldn't you? Or perhaps Other Barry would?

Answer (score 4):

In general, thermistors are the sensor of choice for measuring body temperature. They are sensitive, cheap, and their accuracy is adequate. After all, body temperature does not need to be measured to better than about 0.1 degree F.

With that said, measuring body temperature at the wrist is a losing proposition. There are simply too many chances for wrong temperature readings. The wrist, after all, is out at the end of the arms, with lots of opportunity for heat loss, and who knows what your hands have been holding on to.

Another way to look at it is that all available sensors are inadequate - they measure the actual local temperature rather than the body core temperature.

Comment: I was involved with a skin temperature monitoring project.  There is a literature on skin temp vs core temp, and there is a pretty good relationship -- perhaps not good enough to estimate core temp, but probably good enough to identify febrile conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of monitoring body temperature in a wearable device is were to place the sensor. The skin of arms and legs are known for delivering bad results. The temperature there is some kelvin lower than the body core temperature. The difference is not constant, if you feeel cold, the body reduces the blood flow thru arms and legs in order to keep the body core temperature. The only place for good results is the ear canal.

Comment: Having done some pretty extensive research on the matter in support of an NIH grant application, I disagree.  For example, see http://journals.lww.com/ajpmr/Abstract/2006/07000/Three_Types_of_Skin_Surface_Thermometers__A.1.aspx

Comment: Even in the doctor's office, they now use the skin of the face for core temp

Comment: @Scott Seidman: The abstract is only about the comparison of three different methods to measure skin temperature. But there is no information about the correlation of skin temperature to core temperature.

Comment: Tympanic membrane comparisons (ear canal) are in it too

Comment: They used a infrared thermometer designed to measure tympanic temperature, but they used it at identical spots of each hand, forearm, shoulder, thigh, shin, and foot. I did not found they used it for the ear canal.

Comment: A better study which actually answers the question of reliability of various thermometers in relation to the core body temperature: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijnurstu.2010.11.003

Answer (score 0):

While I’m no expert in bio-monitoring, there are some basic things that leap to mind that may help you decide:

- For continuous monitoring to be useful as a diagnostic tool, the sensor must be accurate, fast (therefore: low thermal mass) and low power because you want as small a battery as possible;
- To minimize the overhead of corrective circuitry it should have as linear an output as possible over the measurable temperature range (which is actually not that large for body temperatures);
- Since conduction, rather than radiation or convection, would be the most efficient heat transfer mechanism in this use case, you’d have to have close and consistent contact with the skin. I’m not sure that’s possible with a loose fitting bracelet or watch.

All of the above leads me to think in terms of an analog semiconductor sensor (over a thermistor or RTD) as part of an adhesive body patch. The packaging may be the most important aspect of the design after the choice of the semiconductor sensor. I did a little bit of research and found a great example of a bio-patch kit with which you could experiment: https://goo.gl/vWrVJq

Comment: Fast would not be important at all for a continuous temperature monitor on the skin, nor would linearity of the sensor, which can be corrected for by software or firmware.

Comment: Such a bio-patch kit measures skin temperature, but only the core temperature is used medically. If the surrounding air temperature is comfortable, the mean skin temp is between 32 to 34 °C. When air has 15 °C, the skin is about 24 °C, the fingers only 16 °C. For short time, the temperature of fingers and toes can be as low as 5 °C without permanent damage.
The normal core temperature of a healthy person is 36,3 to 37,4 °C, a marathon runner may heat up to 38,5 to 39 °C.
The skin temperature of arms and legs is more variable than the skin of the torso.